# Handlebars Uncaught [object Object] error, when compiling on client

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, console, handlebars.js

today got this problem, and can't solve it. I have html template -

```
<script type="text/template" id="usersettings">
<div class="page-header">
  <h3></h3>
</div>
</script>
```

And when trying to compile and attach code to the document

```
var torender = $('#usersettings').html();
var source = Handlebars.compile(torender);
var html = source();
$('#contant').html(html);
```

Got this error from console

```
Uncaught [object Object] handlebars.min.js:25
Handlebars.compile handlebars.min.js:25
Backbone.Router.extend.Settings routes.js:56
(anonymous function) backbone.js:1247
(anonymous function) backbone.js:1452
j.some.j.any underscore.js:208
h.extend.loadUrl backbone.js:1450
h.extend.start backbone.js:1416
(anonymous function)
```

Intresting thing, if I try to do this directly from console, all works fine.

Comment: Can you put `console.log(torender)` after `var torender = $('#usersettings').html();` and see what it prints in console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your DOM is loaded when you try to access the template.
Try to check this code:

```
var torender = $('#usersettings').html();
```

Are you sure that "torender" is actually a string with template's html?